# In wordpress - get the values from an array string to work with post__in

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

> Basically i need help to build a proper array to pass as value of
>   **post__in**

I am working on a wordpress cms. Basically code has to get featured images of posts **only for selected ids**. I need your help to extract the values of the concerned array string in the right manner as currently the code gives a warning `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in .../..`. It still displays images though. The issue is it displays images from across all posts instead of **images only from posts with selected ids**, as intended.

```
$sel_ids = $_SESSION['selected_ids'];

 global $wpdb; 
 require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

 $args = array('post__in' => $sel_ids, 'post_type' => 'post');    
 $posts = get_posts($args);

 foreach ($posts as $post) {
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'coverimage');
 }
```

In the first line of code block above, this string `$sel_ids` carries ids of selected posts. When echoed gives `Array`. When `var_dump($sel_ids)` shows

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "67" [1]=> string(2) "16" }
```

and `foreach` gives a string such as `6716`. I do not need the `foreach` in my code but giving additional info so that it may help you infer better. The code above is not on a template page, but instead on a separate page. it is actually a form-processor. I need the code to run here as I need to grab those values and email them later. So I have loaded WordPress globals. The session is there to carry array values from the form.

---

Got an answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145176/get-the-values-from-an-array-string-to-work-with-post-in).

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($sel_ids)`?  I suspect its your array structure, because otherwise this should work (although **ugh** - why are you loading wp-load outside of wordpress?)

Comment: @cale_b Pl check the bottom of the question for for var_dump results. Got some sql stuff to do thats why I am loading the wp-load.